# OpenCV output of Adaptive Threshold

Tags: python, android, opencv, image-thresholding, adaptive-threshold

I am a newbie in android, and open CV both. However, I am trying to take an image from the camera, convert it into the desired format, and pass it to the tflite model.

Code for capturing image, and applying image processing to it.

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        float mh = mRGBA.height();
        float cw = (float) Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        float scale = mh / cw * 0.7f;

        mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
        frame = classifier.processMat(mRGBA);

        Mat temp = new Mat();
        Mat temp3= new Mat();

        if (!isDebug) {
            if (counter == CLASSIFY_INTERVAL) {
                Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
                Core.rotate(frame, frame, Core.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);
                Imgproc.GaussianBlur(frame, frame, new Size(5, 5), 0);

                Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(frame, frame, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV , 3, 2);

                Bitmap bmsp = null;

                runInterpreter();
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        Imgproc.rectangle(mRGBA,
                new Point(mRGBA.cols() / 2f - (mRGBA.cols() * scale / 2),
                        mRGBA.rows() / 2f - (mRGBA.cols() * scale / 2)),
                new Point(mRGBA.cols() / 2f + (mRGBA.cols() * scale / 2),
                        mRGBA.rows() / 2f + (mRGBA.cols() * scale / 2)),
                new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
        if (isEdge) {
            mRGBA = classifier.debugMat(mRGBA);
        }

        System.gc();
        return mRGBA;
    }
```

My output looks like this image, but I want the hand to be filled with white color before passing it to model. Can somebody suggest?

[image]

[image: original image]

Comment: Post the original image.

Comment: @stateMachine Posted the somewhat similar original picture captured by the phone.

Comment: You can try `cv::findContours` + `cv::fillPoly`

Comment: @Melissa Can I answer with Python code sample?

Comment: @Rotem sure! thanks alot!

Comment: Hi @JOE, Can you please check my code below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that the result of `adaptiveThreshold` has gaps in the external edge, so you can't use it as input to `findContours`.

I think that using `GaussianBlur` makes things worst, because it blurs the edge between the hand and the background.

You may use the following stages:

- Convert frame to Grayscale.
- Apply `adaptiveThreshold` with large kernel size (I used size 51).
  Using a large kernel size, keeps a thick edge line without gaps (except from a small gap at the fingernail).
- Find contours.
  Find the contour with the maximum area.
- Draw the contour (fill with solid value of 255) on a zeros image.
  There is a problem: the inner part of the hand is not filled due to the weird shape of the contour.
- For complete the filling:
  Find the center of the contour, and fill it using `floodFill`.

---

Here is a Python code sample:

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2

frame = cv2.imread("hand.jpg")  # Read image from file (for testing).

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Use BGR to Gray conversion (not RGBA, because image is read from file)

# Apply adaptiveThreshold with large filter size.
thres_gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 51, 2)

# Find contours (external contours)
cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(thres_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Find contour with the maximum area
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

res = np.zeros_like(gray)  # Create new zeros images for storing the result.

# Fill the contour with white color - draw the filled contour on res image.
cv2.drawContours(res, [c], -1, 255, -1)

# Compute the center of the contour
# https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/
M = cv2.moments(c)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

# Use floodFill for filling the center of the contour
cv2.floodFill(res, None, (cX, cY), 255)

# Show images for testing
cv2.imshow('thres_gray', thres_gray)
cv2.imshow('res', res)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Results:

`thres_gray`:
[image]

`res` before `floodFill`:
[image]

`res` after `floodFill`:
[image]

---

JAVA implementation:

```java
package myproject;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Moments;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Sample {
    

static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }


  
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mat frame = Imgcodecs.imread("hand.jpg");
    
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Mat thres_gray = new Mat();
    
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    
    //Apply adaptiveThreshold with large filter size.
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gray, thres_gray, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 51, 2);    
      
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    
    //Find contours
    Imgproc.findContours(thres_gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    //Find contour with the maximum area
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759925/how-to-find-largest-contour-in-java-opencv
    double maxVal = 0;
    int maxValIdx = 0;
    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++)
    {
        double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
        if (maxVal < contourArea)
        {
            maxVal = contourArea;
            maxValIdx = contourIdx;
        }
    }
       
    Mat res = Mat.zeros(gray.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);    //Create new zeros images for storing the result.
    
    Imgproc.drawContours(res, contours, maxValIdx, new Scalar(255), -1);
    
    //Compute the center of the contour
    //https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/
    Moments M = Imgproc.moments(contours.get(maxValIdx));
    int cX = (int)(M.get_m10() / M.get_m00());
    int cY = (int)(M.get_m01() / M.get_m00());    

    //Use floodFill for filling the center of the contour.    
    Mat mask = Mat.zeros(res.rows() + 2, res.cols() + 2, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Imgproc.floodFill(res, mask, new Point(cX, cY), new Scalar(255));
       
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("res.png", res);
}

}
```